# pandas groupby apply list from column based on binary column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
id  to    from    flag
1    a     x        1
1    a     y        0
2    c     z        1
2    c     m        1
2    b     v        0
2    b     p        0
```

and I want to groupby(['id', 'to']) and return a list of the elements in from that have a flag 1 only. If no element has a flag 1, then the resulting output should be 'None'. The desired output should be:

```
id  to  from 
 1   a  ['x']  
 2   c  ['z','m'] 
 2   b  None
```

I can do it with apply i.e.

```
out_df = df.groupby(['id', 'to'])['from'].apply(
       lambda x: match_to_list(x['from'], x['flag'])).reset_index()
```

where:

```
def match_to_list(to, flag):
    matches = list(to.iloc[flag.nonzero()[0]])
    if len(matches) == 0:
        return 'None'
    else:
        matches
```

but this is taking too long and I think there must be a better way that I am missing.

Any help/insights would be very appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC 1st create the index , with `MultiIndex`, then we do `groupby` with `agg`

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(map(tuple,df[['id','to']].drop_duplicates().values.tolist())))
yourdf=df.loc[df.flag==1].groupby(['id','to'])['from'].agg(list).reindex(idx).reset_index()
yourdf
Out[13]: 
   level_0 level_1    from
0        1       a     [x]
1        2       c  [z, m]
2        2       b     NaN
```

Or just using apply , less efficient but more readable

```
df.groupby(['id','to']).apply(lambda x : x['from'][x['flag']==1].tolist() if (x['flag']==1).any() else None).reset_index()
Out[17]: 
   id to       0
0   1  a     [x]
1   2  b    None
2   2  c  [z, m]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was talking about. I went for the first solution. Thank you very much for your help!!